# does stun client launch UDP server to get incoming traffic

Tags: linux, udp, openwrt, stun

I want to know if the STUN client (like stun-client on OpenWrt) open an UDP server to get incoming packet (ether than binding response) or just send binding request to get the public IP address and port.

Answer (score 1):

STUN is a client-server protocol, but that doesn't mean that a STUN "client" can be used as STUN server to get server-reflexive address. It doesn't open any port which will act as STUN server (like port 3478).

Comment: Do you mean that STUN client is used just to get the public IP address?
If we send UDP packet using mapped address from the server side, did we receive it in the client side?

Comment: Yes, STUN is basically a protocol to know the reflexive address. STUN client sends the request to STUN server and it responds with the reflexive address which can be used for many purposes, see old STUN RFC3489 or RFC5780.